# How to update entities in JHipster without losing previous logic work?

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster

I've been exploring into JHipster world, but i find myself with this problem: I can't update an entity (add/delete fields) without messing all my previous logic. What is the best practice to do this?

I tried to make a new branch from master, add my changes to the entity into this new branch, and then make a merge to master again. But it says there is not changes and everything is "up to date", but the true is, that it erese all my customize code and replace for the new one.

I'm using the v6.8.0 for JHipster.

Comment: Is this question about JHipster or git?

Comment: It's about Jhipster. I just post a way i tried to update the entity in Jhipster.

Comment: In JHipster community, this is known as side-by-side approach. Have you seen these presentations? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gg5CYoBdpVo and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9WVpwIUEty0

Comment: Alternatively, you can use git as you tried but specifying merging with this strategy: git merge -s recursive -Xours ... see https://gist.github.com/gmarziou/6cc0788f8e7cb21a61a7b14f32b9a657

Comment: @GaëlMarziou thank you very much. Yes, I've seen the side-by-side approach too but you send me a video that I didn't watch. I think i will have to try that way. Thank you so much for answer me.